# Add mini page layout to related list

Tags: salesforce

Is it possible to add a mini page layout to a related list?  For example, on the opportunity line item related list on the opportunity, I'd like to have a mini page layout display when the user hovers of the product.  Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if it'd be available through configuration. Probably it's not happening because:

- together with rel. lists popping up on top of page when you hover over their names it could mean some messy JS / CSS problems
- it requires that the link on which you hover to have unique id = salesforce record id. If you'd have more than 1 product on Opp Line Items stuff like `document.getElementById()` would always return the first link

the functions that are called are pretty easy to use:

```
<a href="/{!acc.Id}"
    id="{!acc.Id}"
    onblur="LookupHoverDetail.getHover('{!acc.Id}').hide();"
    onfocus="LookupHoverDetail.getHover('{!acc.Id}', '/{!acc.Id}/m?retURL=%2F{!acc.Id}&isAjaxRequest=1').show();"
    onmouseout="LookupHoverDetail.getHover('{!acc.Id}').hide();"
    onmouseover="LookupHoverDetail.getHover('{!acc.Id}', '/{!acc.Id}/m?retURL=%2F{!acc.Id}&isAjaxRequest=1').show();">
    {!acc.Name}
</a>
```

They really require the Id to be record's Id and nothing more though (problem if you'd like to use VF `<apex:outputLink>` etc because id can't be dynamic and it would grow to `page:block:section:table:row:0:accId`.

So - if you really need this feature I suspect you'd have to somehow inject javascript in the sidebar so the Opp Line Item links would be "decorated" using these hover functions. And you'd probably have to override the standard functions / call your own versions so for example they'd display balloon on item that has "oppLineItemId_productId" (that would be unique) but display data from Product2.

The functions can be found for example here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1707/mini-page-layout-css-in-visualforce-page